# create a box with a series of boxes within it with text inside

Tags: html, css

I am looking to create a box with a series of boxes within it that all have their own text centered within them.  I have created a prototype in paint and took a screen shot. does anyone know how I can do this with code? http://screencast.com/t/hFCxwKxxJi5

Thanks!

Comment: Since the `C++` tag was there instead of `css`, I suggest you use an html `table` :)

Comment: -1: What have you tried?

Comment: Do you care about IE7?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with `<table>` tag.
Like this -

```
<table border="2">
  <tr><td colspan="2">Hello</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hello 2</td><td>Hello 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Done. You can style it using CSS if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `colspan` property of `td` to extent text to multiple cells.

```
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="2">Some text here</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Next</td><td>Last</td></tr>
</table>
```

In styles add the below to center the text and draw border

```
<style type="text/css">
    table, td
    {
        padding: 3px 8px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```